# Insert xml to database with full declaration

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have a xml string with declaration such:

```
N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ParentNode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ChildNodes>
    <Node1>106637.5</Node1>
    <Node2>4</Node2>
  </ChildNodes>
</ParentNode>'
```

I had successfully insert to MSSQL database, but it seems sql server automatic trims off the xml declaration (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`).

How can I force sql server to insert above xml string with full declaration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I force sql server to insert above xml string with full
>   declaration ?

It is not possible. [Limitations of the xml Data Type](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187107%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

> The XML declaration PI in an instance is not preserved when the
>   instance is stored in the database.